# How to add more physical disks to a mirror vdev (to increase redundancy)?

Tags: linux, zfs, mirror, zfsonlinux, zpool

Can more physical drives be added to mirror vdevs after a zpool has been created?

For example, if a zpool is created using:

```
zpool create test_pool mirror /dev/sd0 /dev/sd1 mirror /dev/sd2 /dev/sd3
```

Can more drives be added to the vdevs to increase their redundancy? That is, can the number of mirrored drives be increased from 1 to 2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Yes they can.

Something like the following would add to an existing mirror and yield a triple-mirror, given the example above:

```
zpool attach test_pool /dev/sd0 /dev/sd4
zpool attach test_pool /dev/sd2 /dev/sd5
```

Comment: To clarify, I meant to add drives to increase redundancy so that the zpool created by `zpool create test_pool mirror /dev/sd0 /dev/sd1 mirror /dev/sd2 /dev/sd3` would be equivalent to `zpool create test_pool mirror /dev/sd0 /dev/sd1 /dev/sd4 mirror /dev/sd2 /dev/sd3 /dev/sd5` after the drives are added, would those commands do that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I posted.

Comment: @Dave This also works if you have basic vdevs (single disks), they can be converted to mirrors (`attach`) and the mirrors can be degraded back to basic vdevs (`detach`). See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6qvl/index.html for more examples.